# Change the order of table in Mysql using hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have created a table in MYSQL using Hibernate. I get the table like this :-

```
+----+--------+------+
| id | report | Value| 
+----+--------+------+
|  2 |      A |    10 | 
|  5 |      B |    22 | 
|  6 |      C |    23 |
|  7 |      D |    24 |       
+----+--------+------+
```

The order of the table is `id , report ,Value` . But I want the order of the columns in table to be as `id->value->report` using Hibernate.How can I do that ? can anyone please help .Thanks .

Comment: That is not possible if Hibernate is generating your schema. There is some work in progress around position of FK columns for Hibernate 5 but that's about it: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7612

Comment: Then this could be a drawback in Hibernate . Add a upvote for finding a glitch in Hibernate

Comment: Generating the schema using Hibernate is useful for a quick n' dirty POC, but for a real application, schema migrations, etc., you'd better create your schema by yourself anyway.